# What is Cov(X,-X) and P(X-X<0)?

Tags: probability

Assume $X$ is a standard normal random variable. Is $\operatorname{Cov}(X,-X) = -E(X^2)= -1 $ correct?
What will $ P(X-X<0)$ be?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. $X-X = 0$ so $\mathbb P(X-X < 0) = 0$.

Comment: Is P(X-X<=0) = 1?

Comment: Yes, because $0 \le 0$.